# Google Play Internal App Sharing Upload Api Endpoint

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking for a way to upload an `aab` remotely to the google play internal app sharing url. Is this possible? I don't see anything mentioned about it on the [docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Google Play Developer API docs, especially [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/internalappsharingartifacts/uploadbundle).

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/internalappsharing/packageName/artifacts/bundle
```

> Uploads an app bundle to internal app sharing. If you are using the
>   Google API client libraries, please increase the timeout of the http
>   request before calling this endpoint (a timeout of 2 minutes is
>   recommended). See:
>   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors
>   for an example in java.
>
> This method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with
>   the following characteristics:
>
> Maximum file size: 2GB Accepted Media MIME types:
>   application/octet-stream